# Canvas в цикле for

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Честно, даже не знаю как задать вопрос, но суть такова, при переборке массива с шариками Canvas в цикле for, i принимает значение int, почему? Нигде не смог найти почему так, хотя при получении координат он спокойно работает. Мне нужно поменять цвет при ударе об стенку, но указывая configure выдает ошибку о том что это целое число и не имеет такого метода

```python
from tkinter import *
from random import randrange, choices

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)

window = Tk()
window.geometry("600x600")

canvas = Canvas(width=600, height=600, bg='white')
canvas.pack()

color = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']

ball = [[canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 50, 50, fill="red"), [randrange(1, 10), randrange(1, 10)]],
        [canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 50, 50, fill="red"), [randrange(1, 10), randrange(1, 10)]],
        [canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 50, 50, fill="red"), [randrange(1, 10), randrange(1, 10)]],
        [canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 50, 50, fill="red"), [randrange(1, 10), randrange(1, 10)]],
        [canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 50, 50, fill="red"), [randrange(1, 10), randrange(1, 10)]],
        [canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 50, 50, fill="red"), [randrange(1, 10), randrange(1, 10)]],
        [canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 50, 50, fill="red"), [randrange(1, 10), randrange(1, 10)]],
        [canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 50, 50, fill="red"), [randrange(1, 10), randrange(1, 10)]],
        [canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 50, 50, fill="red"), [randrange(1, 10), randrange(1, 10)]],
        [canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 50, 50, fill="red"), [randrange(1, 10), randrange(1, 10)]],
        [canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 50, 50, fill="red"), [randrange(1, 10), randrange(1, 10)]],
        [canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 50, 50, fill="red"), [randrange(1, 10), randrange(1, 10)]],
        [canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 50, 50, fill="red"), [randrange(1, 10), randrange(1, 10)]]]

def move():
    for i in ball:
        canvas.move(i[0], i[1][0], i[1][1])
        if canvas.coords(i[0])[0] <= 0 or canvas.coords(i[0])[2] >= 600:
            
            i[0].configure(fill=choices(color, k=1))
            
            i[1][0] *= -1
        if canvas.coords(i[0])[1] <= 0 or canvas.coords(i[0])[3] >= 600:
            
            i[0].configure(fill=choices(color, k=1))
            
            i[1][1] *= -1
    canvas.after(25, move)
move()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Что означает фраза " i принимает значение int"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё правильно говорит.

`i[0]` - номер объекта на конкретном canvas, число, а у числа нет метода переконфига.

Должно быть примерно так:

```
canvas.itemconfig(i[0], fill=choices(color, k=1)))
```

Comment: Да. этот момент я упустил. Спасибо огромное.